# Changing the size of fonts for dpi

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, dpi

Almost every source about Win32 dpi says that you need to load new scaled fonts.

I tested a simple application (main window and a child ListView, written in pure WinAPI) on *WinXpSP3, Win7* and *Win10* and in all cases the OS always automatically set the correct font size (and even non-client areas) both at startup and when changing the system scaling in runtime. The only thing I had to change manually was the size of the windows themselves and the size of the icons in the ListView.

The application manifest contained
`dpiAware` *True/PM*
`dpiAwareness` *PerMonitorV2, PerMonitor*

And I'm a little confused. It turns out that manual processing of fonts is needed only for owner-drawn controls?

Comment: Why you ask the same question twice?

Comment: Looks like a SO bug, the clone appeared on its own...

Comment: You normally specify the font size in points.  A value with a unit of 1/72 inch.  Which automatically scales with the monitor resolution, an inch on a lo-res monitor is just as much as an inch on a hi-res monitor.  Only sizes with a unit of pixels require correction, window size for example.